# Displaying HTML Source rather than rendering the code in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

I am trying to display the source code of the site using Google App Engine. Here is the snippets of the code that I have tried out.

```
 def post(self):
    s = 'http://www.bing.com'
    fp = urllib.urlopen(s)
    src = fp.read()
    self.response.out.write(template.render('main.html',{'temp1':src}))
```

And the template I have used have some thing similar to

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%">{{temp1}}</div>
```

The problem here is that it renders the source and gives me the html page of the site rather than the code which I am trying to embed. Let me know how to get this solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming that you're using the Django templates that come with Appengine,) you can use the [built-in `escape` filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escape), like:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%">{{temp1|escape}}</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see the html and not the page you gonna need to escape the html entities.
Try: `src = cgi.escape(src)`
And maybe put it inside `<pre></pre>` tags for distinctive displaying.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the HTML code inside the div inside a `<pre>` tag. It's for pre-formatted content. That is, you want the browser to display it exactly the way you write it, so it ignores tags and does not truncate multiple spaces/tabs.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%"><pre>{{temp1}}</pre></div>
```

Comment: [pre](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/block/pre.html) tags do not escape or ignore tags, just some of them.